# How to make multiple balls drop on click?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have a ball that drops from cursor location, and redrops when the cursor is moved to another location. I am trying get a new ball to drop every time I click the mouse. I tried:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  ball.draw();
});
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there some way to draw a NEW ball on click instead of just redrawing the same ball over and over again?

Here's the rest of the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var W = window.innerWidth,
    H = window.innerHeight;
var running = false;

canvas.height = H; canvas.width = W;

var ball = {},
    gravity = .5,
    bounceFactor = .7;

ball = {
  x: W,
  y: H,
  radius: 15,
  color: "BLUE",
  vx: 0,
  vy: 1,

  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
};

function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
}

function update() {
  clearCanvas();
  ball.draw();

  ball.y += ball.vy;

  ball.vy += gravity;
  if(ball.y + ball.radius > H) {
    ball.y = H - ball.radius;
    ball.vy *= -bounceFactor;
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
  ball.x = e.clientX;
  ball.y = e.clientY;
  ball.draw();
});
setInterval(update, 1000/60);

ball.draw();
```

Comment: You should have an array of ball objects and on click, push a new ball object into the array. Then you can iterate the array and draw all the balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite the ball object so it becomes instantiate-able:

```
function Ball(W, H) {
  this.x = W;
  this.y = H;
  this.radius = 15;
  this.color = "blue";
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 1;
```

}

Move the methods to prototypes (this will make them shareable across instances). In addition, add an update method so you can localize updates:

```
Ball.prototype = {
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  },

  update: function() {
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.vy += gravity;
    if(this.y + this.radius > H) {
      this.y = H - this.radius;
      this.vy *= -bounceFactor;
    }
  }
};
```

In the click event (consider renaming the array to plural form - it's easier to distinguish that way. In your code you're overriding the "array" (which is defined as an object) with a single ball object later):

```
var balls = [];                // define an array to hold the balls
```

For the click event to use the x and y position of the mouse as start point for the ball, we first need to adjust it as it is relative to client window and not the canvas. To do this we get the absolute position of canvas and subtract it from the client coordinates:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),  // adjust mouse position
      x = event.clientX - rect.left,
      y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  balls.push(new Ball(x, y));               // add a new instance
});
```

Now in the main animation loop just iterate over the array. Every time there is a new ball it will be considered and updated - we just let the loop run until some condition is met (not shown):

```
function update() {
  clearCanvas();

  for(var i = 0, ball; ball = balls[i]; i++) {
    ball.draw();    // this will draw current ball
    ball.update();  // this will update its position
  }

  requestAnimationFrame();
}
```

## Live example

If you put these together you will get:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    W = canvas.width, // simplified for demo
    H = canvas.height,
    gravity = .5,
    bounceFactor = .7;

function Ball(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = 15;
  this.color = "blue";
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 1
}

Ball.prototype = {
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  },

  update: function() {
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.vy += gravity;  // todo: limit bounce at some point or this value will be added
    if (this.y + this.radius > H) {
      this.y = H - this.radius;
      this.vy *= -bounceFactor;
    }
  }
};

function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
}

var balls = []; // define an array to hold the balls

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),  // adjust mouse position
      x = event.clientX - rect.left,
      y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  balls.push(new Ball(x, y));               // add a new instance
});


(function update() {
  clearCanvas();

  for (var i = 0, ball; ball = balls[i]; i++) {
    ball.draw(); // this will draw current ball
    ball.update(); // this will update its position
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
})();
```

```css
canvas {background:#aaa}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
```